# How to combine LINQ querys with different where conditions

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, sum, where-clause

I have three LINQ querys I'd like to combine. Each query has a different where condition but the group by and select clauses always follow the same pattern. Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Query 1:**

```
    var querySales = from row in bookings.AsEnumerable()
                         where (row.Field<Int32>("t-account") >= tAccSalesFrom && row.Field<Int32>("t-account") <= tAccSalesTo)
                         group row by new
                         {
                             year = row.Field<DateTime>("Date").Year,
                             month = row.Field<DateTime>("Date").Month
                         } into grp
                         orderby grp.Key.year, grp.Key.month
                         select new
                         {
                             Year = grp.Key.year,
                             Month = grp.Key.month,
                             Sales = grp.Sum(row => row.Field<Decimal>("Sales_Assets") - row.Field<Decimal>("Sales_Debit"))
                         };
```

**Query 2:**

```
    var queryLabourCosts = from row in bookings.AsEnumerable()
                               where (row.Field<Int32>("t-account") >= tAccLabFrom && row.Field<Int32>("t-account") <= tAccLabTo)
                               group row by new
                               {
                                   year = row.Field<DateTime>("Date").Year,
                                   month = row.Field<DateTime>("Date").Month
                               } into grp
                               orderby grp.Key.year, grp.Key.month
                               select new
                               {
                                   Year = grp.Key.year,
                                   Month = grp.Key.month,
                                   LabourCosts = grp.Sum(row => row.Field<Decimal>("Sales_Debit") - row.Field<Decimal>("Sales_Assets"))
                               };
```

**Query 3:**

```
    var queryMaterial = from row in bookings.AsEnumerable()
                            where (row.Field<Int32>("t-account") >= tAccMatFrom && row.Field<Int32>("t-account") <= tAccMatTo)
                            group row by new
                            {
                                year = row.Field<DateTime>("Date").Year,
                                month = row.Field<DateTime>("Date").Month
                            } into grp
                            orderby grp.Key.year, grp.Key.month
                            select new
                            {
                                Year = grp.Key.year,
                                Month = grp.Key.month,
                                MaterialCosts = grp.Sum(row => row.Field<Decimal>("Sales_Debit") - row.Field<Decimal>("Sales_Assets"))
                            };
```

**Solution: Thanks to lazyberezovsky!**

```
                var querySalesLabMat = from b in bookings.AsEnumerable()
                               group b by new
                               {
                                   b.Field<DateTime>("Date").Year,
                                   b.Field<DateTime>("Date").Month,
                               } into g
                               orderby g.Key.Year, g.Key.Month
                               select new
                               {
                                   g.Key.Year,
                                   g.Key.Month,
                                   Sales = g.Where(r => r.Field<Int32>("t-account") >= tAccSalesFrom && r.Field<Int32>("t-account") <= tAccSalesTo)
                                                    .Sum(r => r.Field<Decimal>("Sales_Assets") - r.Field<Decimal>("Sales_Debit")),
                                   LabourCosts = g.Where(r => r.Field<Int32>("t-account") >= tAccLabFrom && r.Field<Int32>("t-account") <= tAccLabTo)
                                                  .Sum(r => r.Field<Decimal>("Sales_Debit") - r.Field<Decimal>("Sales_Assets")),
                                   MaterialCosts = g.Where(r => r.Field<Int32>("t-account") >= tAccMatFrom && r.Field<Int32>("t-account") <= tAccMatTo)
                                                  .Sum(r => r.Field<Decimal>("Sales_Debit") - r.Field<Decimal>("Sales_Assets"))
                               };
```

Thanks in advance for your help,
Mat

Comment: Looks like *Find 10 differences* game :)

Comment: There is a good chance that with such complex query you unintentionally move the calculation logic from SQL server (I suspect that you use one) to the client computer what, in turn, will results in huge memory consumption and noticeable delay in query execution (untill all tables from SQL server will be downloaded to you computer ram).

Comment: The reason of this is that not all SQL operations have their counterpart in Linq operation and if in the middle of your complex expression tree there will be at least one that have no SQL analog - this will be that trigger that force the compiler to produce the code to fetch the data from the SQL to local memory and run the query operator over it.

Comment: @Sevenate that is LINQ to DataSet - he already has all data on client

Comment: @lazyberezovsky then it make sense, agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var querySalesLabMat = 
   from b in bookings.AsEnumerable()
   group b by new
   {
       b.Field<DateTime>("Date").Year,
       b.Field<DateTime>("Date").Month,
   } into g
   orderby g.Key.Year, g.Key.Month
   select new
   {
       g.Key.Year,
       g.Key.Month,
       LabourCosts = g.Where(r => r.Field<Int32>("t-account") >= tAccLabFrom && r.Field<Int32>("t-account") <= tAccLabTo)
                      .Sum(r => r.Field<Decimal>("Sales_Debit") - r.Field<Decimal>("Sales_Assets")),
       Sales = g.Where(r => r.Field<Int32>("t-account") >= tAccSalesFrom && r.Field<Int32>("t-account") <= tAccSalesTo)
                .Sum(r => r.Field<Decimal>("Sales_Assets") - r.Field<Decimal>("Sales_Debit")),
       MaterialCosts = g.Where(r => r.Field<Int32>("t-account") >= tAccMatFrom && r.Field<Int32>("t-account") <= tAccMatTo)
                        .Sum(r => r.Field<Decimal>("Sales_Debit") - r.Field<Decimal>("Sales_Assets"))
   };
```

Comment: Thanks a million! I don't know why I wasn't able to set the where condition correct. I modified the answer a little bit and it solved my issues.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like:

```
var querySales = from row in bookings.AsEnumerable()
                         where (row.Field<Int32>("t-account") >= tAccSalesFrom && row.Field<Int32>("t-account") <= tAccSalesTo)
                         where (row.Field<Int32>("t-account") >= tAccLabFrom && row.Field<Int32>("t-account") <= tAccLabTo)
                         where (row.Field<Int32>("t-account") >= tAccMatFrom && row.Field<Int32>("t-account") <= tAccMatTo)
                         group row by new
                         {
                             year = row.Field<DateTime>("Date").Year,
                             month = row.Field<DateTime>("Date").Month
                         } into grp
                         orderby grp.Key.year, grp.Key.month
                         select new
                         {
                             Year = grp.Key.year,
                             Month = grp.Key.month,
                             Sales = grp.Sum(row => row.Field<Decimal>("Sales_Assets") - row.Field<Decimal>("Sales_Debit"))

                             //Group by year and month and sum based on the t-account
                               Sales = grp.Where().Sum(),
                               LabourCosts = grp.Where().Sum(),
                               MaterialCosts = = grp.Where().Sum()
                         };
```

?

Comment: This will only select rows which match all conditions (for sales, labour costs, and for material costs). But there are rows which match sales filter only and should be used for sales calculation